# Excel: Count cells with zero value until first non zero

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet in Excel 2013 that needs to look roughly like the following:

**[example sheet]**

[image]

Column A will just return their own row numbers, Column B will have numbers, I need a formula to put in Column C to return the row numbers of Non Zero values. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What have you already tried? Show that you have done at least some effort.

Comment: I can't remember all the things that I tried, most of it involved a google search, finding a post that looked similar and trying that and modifying the formula to suit but nothing worked. Mostly some array formulas. But when I couldn't get them to work I discarded them and moved on. I had a formula in place but it only works when there is a single zero value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this is C2,

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($2:$15)/(B$2:B$15<>0), ROW(1:1))
```

Fill down as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Let Column C equal function (drag down):

=IF( B1>0, A1, 0)

Then filter on Column C only values greater than 0.

Comment: this small section is going to be put into a larger sheet where filtering is not a viable option for what else needs to happen